# Specifying upload_to parameter in the model does not seem to do anything

Tags: python, django

My model looks like this:

```
class MainSample(models.Model):
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audio')
```

In the following view, I am creating this model's instance and saving it:

```
from .models import MainSample

def index(request):
    MainSample.objects.all().delete()
    main_sample = MainSample()
    main_sample.audio = 'audio/main_sample.mp4' # why do I need to prepend this with 'audio'?
    main_sample.save()
    context = {
        'main_sample': main_sample,
    }
    return render(request, 'mediaapp/index.html', context)
```

And next creating an audio element in the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <body>
            <audio controls src="{{main_sample.audio.url}}"</div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The audio file is pre-downloaded and sits in `MEDIA_ROOT/audio/`.

The code works, but I don't understand the purpose of `upload_to` parameter in the model definition, even after reading about it in the Django docs.

It is supposed to append `audio` path to my `MEDIA_ROOT`, yet in the view I still need to prepend the value of `main_sample.audio` with `audio/`, otherwise the template will not load the audio file.

Could someone explain in plain words what does the `upload_to` does in this context, and if I can possibly get rid of writing `audio/` again in my view?

Comment: Well, you're not uploading anything in this code so why would you expect that parameter to be used?

Comment: @DanieRoseman: I thought that putting the file manually in the folder can be considered "uploading", and the value of `upload_to` will be appended to the file path when the `.save()` method is called on the model's instance. Is it only for model forms then?